# Comment faire une proposition relative dans ce cas? (faire confiance à)

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

J'aimerais dire en français "He is someone I trust." Pour dire "I trust him", on dirait "Je fais confiance à lui", mais je ne sais pas comment le faire la phrase susdite. Dit-on "Il est quelqu'un **à qui** je fais confiance", "Il est quelqu'un **où** je fais confiance", ou bien quelque chose d'autre ?

Comment: Just a sidenote: *susdite* is an extremely formal way of refering to a previous sentence/statement that is hardly ever used outside laws stuff.

Comment: *Je fais confiance à lui* implique une situation où on ferait un contraste entre *lui* et quelqu'un d'autre par exemple en le montrant du doigt. Dans les contextes standards, on utilise le pronom sur le verbe : *Je lui fais confiance* (cf la réponse de cl-r). Par ailleurs, pour le présentatif, on utilise plutôt *C'est quelqu'un à qui...*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I trust him** :

> - Je lui fais confiance.

ou plus littéraire, avec transposition :

> - J'ai confiance en lui.

**He is someone I trust** :

> - C'est quelqu'un *à qui* je fais confiance.

... traduction courante

> - C'est quelqu'un *en qui* j'ai confiance.

... transposition plus littéraire, un peu plus 'élégante'.